# Cloning VBScript Err Object

Tags: object, error-handling, vbscript, clone

The below code gives the error `Variable is undefined (500)` when trying to concatenate the error.no in the echo:

```
'Raise an error to represent an issue with the main code
err.raise 999

dim error
set error = err

'Call another function that could also throw an error
SendMail "To=me","From=me","Subject=Failure in main code"

'Report both errors
wscript.echo "First problem was - Error code:" & error & vbcrlf & "Subsequent problem was - Error code:" & err
```

Is it possible to clone the err object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Ekkehard.Horner, you can also create a custom error class with the same behaviour as the error object. Because the err object is global, you can load it inside the class without passing it to it in a method.

```
On error resume Next
a = 1 / 0
Set myErr = new ErrClone
On error goto 0

WScript.Echo myErr  
' returns 11, the default property
WScript.Echo myErr.Number & vbTab & myErr.Description & vbTab & myErr.Source
' returns 11      Division by zero      Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Class ErrClone

    private description_, number_, source_

    Public Sub Class_Initialize
        description_ = Err.Description
        number_ = Err.Number
        source_ = Err.Source
    End Sub

    Public Property Get Description
        Description = description_
    End Property
    Public Default Property Get Number
        Number = number_
    End Property
    Public Property Get Source
        Source = source_
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy the properties of the global Err object to a new variable for later use (after the global Err was changed by new catastrophies. .Clear, or "On Error GoTo 0") you should use an array:

```
>> On Error Resume Next
>> a = 1 / 0
>> Dim aErr : aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source)
>> On Error GoTo 0
>> WScript.Echo Join(aErr, "-")
>>
11-Division by zero-Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

because you can't create an empty Err object in VBScript.